# Best way to implement google map on Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps, laravel-5

What is the best way to implement google map on laravel? I looked up for some packages and dont know what to use. And I found some js like gmaps.js. The features that I want to achieve are these:
1. Location of the user
2. Search for a location and then set a marker for that
3. Directions/Routes
4. Map styles/Design
5.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to  use javascript google map api if thire not famailer with you then you can use laraval package lots of available on packagist